# Changing font size on Math.StackExchange?

Tags: discussion, support, markdown, font

Is there a way to make a selected text bigger/smaller? And which is the best?

Comment: Your browser can almost certainly do this. Is that not what you're looking for?

Comment: No, I meant when I'm writing a question/answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thinking about it, I also realize that we could $\Large\text{use LaTeX}$ in ways that are $\Huge\text{still of questionable merit}$, but which fit inline. Note that we can't ${\fontsize{3cm}{1em}\selectfont use an arbitrary fontsize}$. But then again, some might ask $\Tiny\text{why we would do this at all.}$

---

Here is the source for this answer.

```
Thinking about it, I also realize that we could
$\Large\text{use LaTeX}$ in ways that are
$\Huge\text{still of questionable merit}$,
but which fit inline. Note that we can't
${\fontsize{3cm}{1em}\selectfont use an arbitrary fontsize}$.
But then again, some might ask
$\Tiny\text{why we would do this at all.}$
```

Comment: I thought of latex but they should add something more... functional (like the **B** button for Bold).
We whould do this to emphasize the text that some people are ignoring just to answer as quickly as the can and get to misleading answers that try to solve what *they* wanted their question to be.

Comment: 1 more thing: Why don't you join these answers? As two seperate options?

Comment: @user2692669, if you want to emphasise text then you have `*` and `**`.

Comment: They obviously need something more special with a little kick in it ;)

Comment: ouch thanks now my eyeballs hurt !

Comment: Ironically, I find this answer artistically quite beautiful.

Comment: So how do you use that in the editor?

Comment: It sure would be nice if someone answered @Qwerty. As it stands, this is a useless answer. Ok, it's possible. Now how do you do it? I had to create an account on this community (which I'm sure no one wants a bunch of inactive members) just to comment here. You can't even click edit to hopefully see what markup it is. It would have been decent to at least add a section below your cutesy response for a real answer.

Comment: @RKS The answer is: yes, it's possible; no, you should not do it. (And even if you do, someone will likely revert the changes.) The standard font size is standard. People with poor vision can use tools for that purpose, such as browser zoom.

Comment: The question isn't, "Should I do this." The question is, "How do I do this." Adding any caveat about shouldn't do it is fine, but without an actual answer, my statement stands. This is a useless answer.

Comment: I love and hate this answer, The reason I love it is because it shows me exactly what I want to accomplish. The reason I hate it is because "Suggested edits are not allowed on non-tag-wiki posts on meta sites." This is a useless answer.

Comment: So I also just created an account on this Stack Exchange just to leave this comment. I wish I had 125 reputation to be able to downvote this answer. We can't even edit it to see how it was written. This answer would be awesome with a simple `Quote block` showing the raw text that was used. Useless answer as it is

Answer (score 9):

## I suppose if you really wanted to

Then you could

### vary it up by abusing headers

But this

#### hurts my sensibilities

Comment: As you said, that's abuse and front-end designers whould commit suicude if they saw something like that (it would be sooooo out of context).

Answer (score 6):

you could use simple `#` but only for headers/one full line.

"### Text"

#### Text

---

"## Text"

### Text

---

"# Text"

## Text

---

*answer here for others, because its first web-site from google-search while looking for exactly this.

Comment: 2 upvoted troll answers and only one that actually tries to answer the question (8 years late). This stack seems to be cancer.

Answer (score 0):

Just a sharing for someone may need it:

```
$\tiny{\text{testbowman}}$

$\scriptsize{\text{testbowman}}$

$\small{\text{testbowman}}$

$\normalsize{\text{testbowman}}$

$\large{\text{testbowman}}$

$\Large{\text{testbowman}}$

$\LARGE{\text{testbowman}}$

$\huge{\text{testbowman}}$

$\Huge{\text{testbowman}}$
```

Result：

$\tiny{\text{testbowman}}$

$\scriptsize{\text{testbowman}}$

$\small{\text{testbowman}}$

$\normalsize{\text{testbowman}}$

$\large{\text{testbowman}}$

$\Large{\text{testbowman}}$

$\LARGE{\text{testbowman}}$

$\huge{\text{testbowman}}$

$\Huge{\text{testbowman}}$

Comment: Just share for those who were extremely curious about how David's answer achieved the requirement. This looks like purely available in StackExchange but completely banned in Stack Overflow currently...

Comment: It is available wherever MathJaX is enabled.  (Roughly, sites involving lots of mathematics.)